# Problem with errorPlacement in validator plugin jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, validation

I am using the validator plugin of jQuery. By default the error label is added below my form. I want to add it above my form. So what I am doing is adding the code below in the validate():

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) { 
    error.insertBefore('form#emailForm');
 }
```

The problem is that the error label now is added a lot of times above the form, in every click. So I have something like this:

```
Enter valid email.Enter valid email.Enter valid email.
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If they're getting added lots of times all you have to do is remove them before they're added.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) { 
    $('.error').remove();
    error.insertBefore('#emailForm');
}
```

Comment: You'll need to customize the selector so it only targets your error elements. 

Add a sample URL to your question and i'll do it for you.